# background music stops after 3/4 runs in iphone app

Tags: iphone, audio, media-player, audiotoolbox

I am playing sounds in loop in my app. So it should continue playing through out the app. but sometimes it stops after playing sound for 3/4 times.I don't understand whats happening. 
I am using audio-toolbox framework for playing sound. creating audio queue and then playing sounds in loop. I am also playing sound from ipod library using mediaplayer. Same thing happening with song from ipod. 
I have set [musicPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeOne]; but still it stops after 3/4 times.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you playing the sound? Show us the code. Do you use System Sound Services? They are not meant to play longer sounds, quote [Audio Toolbox Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAAudioTooboxRef/index.html):

> You can use System Sound Services to
>   play short (30 seconds or less)
>   sounds.

This could be the source of your problem. But until you show us the code we can’t but guess.